# Combobox KeyPressEventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling, keypress

I have a windows form that contains comboboxes. I want to set `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` properties as "`true`" to block data input via keyboard for each combobox. Because comboboxes have its items defined and I want no input data from user. Is there a way to do this via using foreach spinnet or like that?

Comment: Unclear. Why foreach? for many number of comboboxes or to block characters? What are the characters you need to prevent? give more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set ComboBox's Style property to DropDownList which prevents entering any character into comboBox and allows just selecting from internal items.

```
comboBox.Style = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

you can do this from designer or you can iterate on comboBoxes and set Style property programmatically.